# How can I display 20230324213000 in date time using flatlist in react native

Tags: react-native, momentjs, react-native-flatlist

I have made use of moment.js for displaying the date and time but its not working so if possible can I get help on this topic

```
<FlatList
                            refreshControl={
                                <RefreshControl
                                    refreshing={refresh}
                                    onRefresh={() => {
                                        pullMe();
                                        getScore();
                                    }}
                                />
                            }
                            keyExtractor={(index) => {
                                return index.Sid
                            }}
                            data={myData}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                                return (
                                    <View>
                                        <View style={hr101} />
                                        <Text style={league}>{item.Snm}</Text>
                                        <Text style={league2}>{item.Cnm}</Text>
                                        <View>
                                            {item.Events.map((event) => (
                                                <View style={match}>
                                                    <Text style={league2}>{event.EtTx}-{event.ErnInf}</Text>
                                                    <Text style={status1}>{event.EpsL} {moment( event.Esd ).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}</Text> __//this line event.Esd will return 20230324213000__
                                                    <View style={hr100} />
                                                    <Text style={teams1}>{event.T1[0].Nm} </Text>
                                                    <Text style={teams}>
                                                        {event.Tr1C2 !== undefined && event.Tr1CW2 !== undefined && event.Tr1CO2 !== undefined ? (<Text style={teams}>{event.Tr1C1}-{event.Tr1CW1} ({event.Tr1CO1} Ovs){"\n"}&{"\n"}{event.Tr1C2}-{event.Tr1CW2} ({event.Tr1CO2} Ovs)</Text>) : event.Tr1C1 !== undefined && event.Tr1CW1 !== undefined && event.Tr1CO1 !== undefined ? (<Text>{event.Tr1C1}-{event.Tr1CW1} ({event.Tr1CO1} Ovs)</Text>) : (<Text style={teams_yet}>Yet to bat</Text>)}
                                                    </Text>
                                                    <View style={hr100} />
                                                    <Text style={teams1}>{event.T2[0].Nm} </Text>
                                                    <Text style={teams}>
                                                        {event.Tr2C2 !== undefined && event.Tr2CW2 !== undefined && event.Tr2CO2 !== undefined ? (<Text style={teams}>{event.Tr2C1}-{event.Tr2CW1} ({event.Tr2CO1} Ovs){"\n"}&{"\n"}{event.Tr2C2}-{event.Tr2CW2} ({event.Tr2CO2} Ovs)</Text>) : event.Tr2C1 !== undefined && event.Tr2CW1 !== undefined && event.Tr2CO1 !== undefined ? (<Text>{event.Tr2C1}-{event.Tr2CW1} ({event.Tr2CO1} Ovs)</Text>) : (<Text style={teams_yet}>Yet to bat</Text>)}
                                                    </Text>
                                                    <View style={hr100} />
                                                    <Text style={result}>{event.ECo}</Text>
                                                </View>
                                            ))}
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                );
                            }}
                        />
```

event.Esd will be the given string which I want to transform into date time
The line of code is displaying January 28th 2611, 12:00:13 pm
whereas it should return March 24th 2023, 9:30:00 pm

Comment: can you tell us what exactly is the value of event.Esd ?

Comment: the value of event.Esd is today's date and time(20230324213000) in which first four numbers will be year(2023) then next two will be month(03) and next two will be date(24) and remaining characters will be time and all of this is received as a response from API

Comment: According to the timestamp, the output seems right. Try it out here, https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Yes according to epoch its right but event.Esd is not in epoch format it is just a string in the format I mentioned in above comment and I would like to display that string in date time format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below snippet. Following the correct format specifiers will give you the expected output. You should pass in the input format as the second parameter to the `moment()`. Format specifier `Do` will give you the number ordinal. Rest of them look straight forward.

```js
const str = "20230324213000";
console.log(moment(str, "YYYYMMDDhmss a").format("MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Heyy its working fine by doing this Thank You!!